# How to get results from specific dates (2016-01-01 / 2016-12-31)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a SQL query that calculates the DATEDIFF between columns based on a year from today. Now, I'm trying to get the data between (2016-01-01/2016-12-31).

This is the query below that gets the date based on a year time from today. Could anybody give me an idea of how to just get work between (2016-01-01/2016-12-31)?

```
sum(case 
 when ci.docdate#2 >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())  and ci.docdate#5>= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) and ci.docdate#5 <= getdate() then (DATEDIFF(day,ci.docdate#2,ci.docdate#5)-(DATEDIFF(week,ci.docdate#2,ci.docdate#5)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.docdate#2) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.docdate#2) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 when ci.docdate#2 >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())   and (ci.docdate#5 > getdate() or year(ci.docdate#5) <2000) then (DATEDIFF(day,ci.docdate#2,getdate())-(DATEDIFF(week,ci.docdate#2,getdate())*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.docdate#2) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.docdate#2) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 when ci.docdate#2 < DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())  and  ci.docdate#5>= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) and ci.docdate#5 <= getdate()  then (DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()),ci.docdate#5)-(DATEDIFF(week,DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()),ci.docdate#5)*2))+1 - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, '2020-01-01') = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 when ci.docdate#2 < DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) and (ci.docdate#5 > getdate() or year(ci.docdate#5) <2000) then (DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()),getdate())-(DATEDIFF(week,DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()),getdate())*2))+1 - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, '2020-01-01') = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 when year(ci.docdate#2) < 1900  and  ci.docdate#5 >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())  then (DATEDIFF(day,ci.deldate,ci.docdate#5)-(DATEDIFF(week,ci.deldate,ci.docdate#5)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.deldate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.deldate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 when year(ci.docdate#2) < 1900  and (ci.docdate#5 > getdate() or year(ci.docdate#5) <2000) then (DATEDIFF(day,ci.deldate,getdate())-(DATEDIFF(week,ci.deldate,getdate())*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.deldate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, ci.deldate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 else 0
 end) as DaysonHire
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using. DATEDIFF and DATEADD are product specific functions.

Comment: Replace getdate() with 2016-12-31?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio